# How to change user password remotely using Windows PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, networking, server, powershell-2.0, powershell-remoting

friends.

I am trying to change password remotely of my server, because I cannot access it using Remote Desktop.
So I found a way in Youtube for changing user password for the local computer using this code:

```
Get-Localuser
$NewPassword = ConvertTo-SecureString "123" -AsPlainText -Force

Set-LocalUser -Name Admin-Password $NewPassword
```

but I want to change the user password on another computer (server), how can I do it?

Comment: What were your errors when trying with Invoke-Command or Enter-PSSession?

Comment: the code above works correctly, but I want to do the same code for another computer remotely.

Comment: Have a look at [Invoke-Command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command)

Comment: [see](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-r2-and-2012/cc771865(v=ws.11))